# Link a treenode(Primefaces) to an xhtml page

Tags: xhtml, primefaces

i have created the tree with its nodes and i would like to put an action on each node to move it to an xhtml form say(ManageUser.xhtml) when i click on the node(say Manage User).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this example from the Primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/treeSelectionAjax.jsf) showcase.

You could use a select listener and redirect from the backing bean method:

```
<p:tree value="#{treeBean.root}" var="node"  
            selectionMode="single"  
            selection="#{treeBean.selectedNode}"  
            nodeSelectListener="#{treeBean.onNodeSelect}">  
        <p:treeNode>  
            <h:outputText value="#{node}" />  
        </p:treeNode>  
</p:tree>
```

and in the bean:

```
public void onNodeSelect(NodeSelectEvent event) {  
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Selected", event.getTreeNode().getData().toString());  
        // redirect here
}
```